# How to get a JS Date object from a UTC timestamp

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, utc

I get my UTC timestamp from the POCO libraries where the docs say:

> Returns the timestamp expressed in UTC-based time. UTC base time is midnight, October 15, 1582. Resolution is 100 nanoseconds.

With this I could do something like

```
// utctime = 136288658313819610
d = new Date(0);
d.setUTCMilliseconds(utctime / 1000 / 10);
// d = Date 2401-11-18T12:03:51.381Z
```

When using a current utctime, the resulting date is sometime in year 2401, which seems about right with an epoch in year 1582.

To convert it to a correct UTC time, I would need to initialize `Date` with some negative value that represents the difference of the epochs, but I was unable to find such a value.

I also need to convert the UTC time to local time for a useful result, but for that I would have to default initialize the `Date` object, right? Maybe this can be done with subtraction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! You can set the epoch manually without calculating the exact second difference of the epochs. The timezone is available with getTimezoneOffset.

```
// utctime = 136288807241160530
d = new Date();
d.setFullYear(1582);
d.setMonth(9);
d.setDate(15);
d.setHours(0);
d.setMinutes(-d.getTimezoneOffset());
d.setSeconds(0);
d.setMilliseconds(utctime / 1000 / 10);
// d = Date 2014-09-01T16:12:04.116Z
```